# Fullscreen GUI App on Raspbian startup

Tags: python, python-3

i'm working on a Simple DIY Home Control project
Language is Python, and GUI is PyQT5
The project is just some ESPs connected to a main Raspberry Pi (3B+) controller

The problem is that I'm trying to run the application at fullscreen, but i keep getting the Desktop to start, and then the app.
What I need instead is only the application to start,
without the Desktop and Applications bar to start.

Can you suggest me what I can try to use?
I'm going to use a touch screen, and need to keep the ability to click to interact with the application itself.

Thanks in advance for every help you can give me.
Kind regards

Comment: Do a google search for "rpi kiosk" and you will find lots of options/solutions for this. I have not done it myself, so cannot really say which option is better.

Comment: not really a Raspberry Pi question ... it is a Linux question ... research `how to start a program instead of a DM (desktop manager)`

Answer (score 1):

Though this is not a Raspberry PI question, I am seeing this is being asked often nowadays

This is what worked for me with Raspberry Pi OS (Debian 10)

This was done on Debian with LXDE desktop. I wrote an automated setup script for my software, copying some snippet from that here.

###### Step 1. Disable the LXDE desktop:

I had commented out lxpanel and xscreensaver both from the default autostart and user autostart

```
  #DISABLE THE DESKTOP
  sudo sed -i 's/^@lxpanel/#@lxpanel/g' /etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE/autostart
  sudo sed -i 's/^@xscreensaver/#@xscreensaver/g' /etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE/autostart
  #DISABLE THE DESKTOP FOR THE USER
  sudo sed -i 's/^@lxpanel/#@lxpanel/g' /etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE-${user_name}/autostart
  sudo sed -i 's/^@xscreensaver/#@xscreensaver/g' /etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE-${user_name}/autostart
```

###### Step 2. Setup the application:

> Note: I was using python3.7

```
#SETUP PYTHON VENV
python3 -m venv ${application_root_dir}/venv
cd ${application_root_dir}/venv
source ${application_root_dir}/venv/bin/activate

# Install external dependencies, if any
pip3 install <dependecny_name>

# Install your software
pip3 install <software>
deactivate
```

###### Step 3. Prepare for Autostart (optional):

Create Script to be executed in autostart. Note this is optional, you can directly use your command in the auto start (step 4).

```
tee -a ${application_root_dir}/start_my_app.sh > /dev/null << EOT
#!/bin/bash
cd ${application_root_dir}
source venv/bin/activate
python3 -m package.MyApp
deactivate
EOT

# Set execute permissions
sudo chmod 744 ${root_dir}/start_my_app.sh
```

###### Step 4. Setup Autostart:

> Note: you can execute any command by setting `ExecStart` in `[service]`

###### 4.1 Create a new service

```
# CREATE A SERVICE FILE
sudo tee -a /etc/systemd/system/my_app.service > /dev/null << EOT
[Unit]
Description=Start MY_APPLICATION
After=default.target
Wants=default.target

[Service]
User=${user_name}
Group=$user_group
Environment=DISPLAY=:0.0
Environment=XAUTORITY=/home/${user_name}/.Xauthority
ExecStart=/bin/bash -c "${root_dir}/start_my_app.sh"

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
EOT
```

###### 4.2 Register and enable the service

```
sudo /usr/bin/systemctl daemon-reload
sudo /usr/bin/systemctl enable my_app.service
```

###### 4.3 Reboot

```
sudo reboot
```

> Note: To enable the desktop back for troubleshooting (if at all required - I never needed though, as ssh was enabled in my case so I was using terminal). Uncomment the commented part of lxde deskop and reboot.