# VideoPlayer using python, tkinter and pythong-vlc

Tags: python, pi-4, vlc, tkinter

I have created a video (with audio) player using vlc on Raspberry pi 4 board. Code and other details below. I have an HDMI screen attached on HDMI-1.
I am hiding the desktop using [this approach](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/135965/fullscreen-gui-app-on-raspbian-startup/135984#135984).

This code runs okay and I can see the video, however, there are two different symptoms I am facing. I don't know the problem though.

#### Symptom 1:

1. The logs show below error (I have been trying to understand these logs and searching over internet for a few days - unfortunately, no luck with any of the proposed solutions).
   I have tried adding '--vout=mmal_vout' as suggested [here](https://github.com/RPi-Distro/vlc/issues/30), but no luck.

```
Apr 27 11:51:36 CAPSCREEN01 bash[605]: [974206a8] mmal_codec decoder: VCSM init succeeded: CMA
Apr 27 11:51:36 CAPSCREEN01 bash[605]: [974206a8] main decoder error: buffer deadlock prevented
Apr 27 11:51:37 CAPSCREEN01 bash[605]: [9730e6b0] mmal_xsplitter vout display error: Failed to open Xsplitter:opengles2 module
Apr 27 11:51:47 CAPSCREEN01 bash[605]: [9741e8e8] mmal_codec decoder: VCSM init succeeded: CMA
Apr 27 11:51:47 CAPSCREEN01 bash[605]: [9741e8e8] main decoder error: buffer deadlock prevented
Apr 27 11:51:48 CAPSCREEN01 bash[605]: [a8c05cd0] mmal_xsplitter vout display error: Failed to open Xsplitter:opengles2 module
Apr 27 11:51:58 CAPSCREEN01 bash[605]: [97421ed8] mmal_codec decoder: VCSM init succeeded: CMA
Apr 27 11:51:58 CAPSCREEN01 bash[605]: [97421ed8] main decoder error: buffer deadlock prevented
Apr 27 11:51:59 CAPSCREEN01 bash[605]: [a8122398] mmal_xsplitter vout display error: Failed to open Xsplitter:opengles2 module
```

#### Symptom 2:

When the video loops, the whole screen refreshes (below two methods)

```py
    movie_player.set_play_mode(1)
    movie_player.play_video(0)
```

Any help to identify the problem and suggest a solution will be greatly appreciated.

My main objective here is to create a video player. I choose VLC since it has all the features that I need, i.e. playing MP4 file with Audio and Video, looping through single video, getting callback event when video finishes.

Now, I am open to change the player provided I get above features.

#### Video Player Code

```py
import tkinter as tk
import sys
import os

import vlc

_isMacOS = sys.platform.startswith('darwin')
_isWindows = sys.platform.startswith('win')
_isLinux = sys.platform.startswith('linux')


class VideoPlayer:
    def __init__(self, parent, videos):
        self.parent = parent  # == root

        # first, top panel shows video
        self.video_frame = tk.Frame(self.parent)
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self.video_frame)
        self.canvas.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)
        self.show()

        # VLC player
        args = []
        if _isLinux:
            args.append('--no-xlib')
            args.append('--vout=mmal_vout')

        # Create vlc instance
        self.Instance = vlc.Instance(args)

        # Create Player
        self.player = self.Instance.media_player_new()
        self.player.video_set_mouse_input(True)

        # Create Media List Player (this is required to play video in a loop)
        self.playlist = self.Instance.media_list_player_new()

        # Set playback mode to loop
        # self.list_player.set_playback_mode(vlc.PlaybackMode.loop)
        self.set_play_mode(0)

        # Set Media Player to created player
        self.playlist.set_media_player(self.player)

        # Create list of media
        self.media_list = self.Instance.media_list_new(videos)

        # set media list to the player
        self.playlist.set_media_list(self.media_list)

        # set the window id where to render VLC's video output
        h = self.canvas.winfo_id()  # .winfo_visualid()?
        if _isWindows:
            self.player.set_hwnd(h)
        elif _isLinux:
            self.player.set_xwindow(h)  # fails on Windows

    def attached_end_video_event(self, callback):
        # Create an event manager object
        # self.player.event_manager().event_attach(vlc.EventType.MediaPlayerEndReached, callback)
        list_event_manager = self.playlist.event_manager()
        list_event_manager.event_attach(vlc.EventType.MediaListPlayerNextItemSet, callback)
        list_event_manager.event_attach(vlc.EventType.MediaListPlayerPlayed, callback)

    def stop(self, event=None):
        self.playlist.play_item_at_index(1)
        self.set_play_mode(0)

    def show(self):
        if not self.video_frame.winfo_viewable():
            self.video_frame.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)

    def hide(self):
        self.video_frame.pack_forget()

    def play_video(self, index):
        itm = self.media_list.item_at_index(index)
        self.player.set_media(itm)
        output = self.playlist.play_item(itm)

    def set_play_mode(self, mode):
        """
            0: 'default': stop after playing videos
            1: 'loop'
            2: 'repeat'
        :param mode:
        :return:
        """
        # Set playback mode to loop
        self.playlist.set_playback_mode(mode)


def startup():
    videos = [
        "Video1.mp4",
        "Video2.mp4",
        "Video3.mp4",
        "Video4.mp4"
        ]
    movie_player = VideoPlayer(root, videos)
    movie_player.set_play_mode(1)
    movie_player.play_video(0)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.geometry("640x480")
    
    root.after(1000, startup)
    root.mainloop()
```

##### Board

```bash
#> cat /sys/firmware/devicetree/base/model
Raspberry Pi 4 Model B Rev 1.4
```

##### OS

```bash
#> cat /etc/os-release
PRETTY_NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)"
NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="10"
VERSION="10 (buster)"
VERSION_CODENAME=buster
ID=raspbian
ID_LIKE=debian
HOME_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianForums"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianBugs"
```

##### Screen

```
#> tvservice -s -l
state 0x6 [DVI CUSTOM RGB full 4:3], 1600x1200 @ 60.00Hz, progressive
1 attached device(s), display ID's are :
Display Number 2, type HDMI 0
```

#### Troubleshooting done:

Initially I was getting below error and there was not video shown.

```
Apr 27 11:04:37 CAPSCREEN01 bash[1417]: [9745cbb8] mmal_codec filter error: Failed to enable output port vc.ril.hvs:out:0(BGRA) (status=1 ENOMEM)
Apr 27 11:04:37 CAPSCREEN01 bash[1417]: mmal: mmal_vc_port_enable: failed to enable port vc.ril.hvs:out:0(BGRA): ENOMEM
Apr 27 11:04:37 CAPSCREEN01 bash[1417]: mmal: mmal_port_enable: failed to enable port vc.ril.hvs:out:0(BGRA)(0x974014f0) (ENOMEM)
```

After reading reading somewhere (I find that link now. I increased the GPU Memory to 256).
It started showing me the video after this update.

#### VLC Plugins

```
#> ls -l /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/vlc/plugins/mmal/
total 960
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 140796 Jan 18  2021 libmmal_avcodec_plugin.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 272032 Jan 18  2021 libmmal_codec_plugin.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 136596 Jan 18  2021 libmmal_converter_plugin.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 140744 Jan 18  2021 libmmal_deinterlace_plugin.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 140748 Jan 18  2021 libmmal_vout_plugin.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 136596 Jan 18  2021 libmmal_xsplitter_plugin.so

#> ls -l /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/vlc/plugins/video_output/
total 368
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  9620 Jan 18  2021 libaa_plugin.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 13768 Jan 18  2021 libcaca_plugin.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  9620 Jan 18  2021 libegl_wl_plugin.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  9620 Jan 18  2021 libegl_x11_plugin.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 13708 Jan 18  2021 libfb_plugin.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  9620 Jan 18  2021 libflaschen_plugin.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 58836 Jan 18  2021 libgles2_plugin.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 67028 Jan 18  2021 libgl_plugin.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  9620 Jan 18  2021 libglx_plugin.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  9664 Jan 18  2021 libvdummy_plugin.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  9612 Jan 18  2021 libvmem_plugin.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 13772 Jan 18  2021 libwl_shell_plugin.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 13796 Jan 18  2021 libwl_shm_plugin.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 21908 Jan 18  2021 libxcb_window_plugin.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 13724 Jan 18  2021 libxcb_x11_plugin.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 21920 Jan 18  2021 libxcb_xv_plugin.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 13880 Jan 18  2021 libxdg_shell_plugin.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  9612 Jan 18  2021 libyuv_plugin.so


#> ls -l /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/vlc/plugins/video_splitter/
total 64
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  9680 Jan 18  2021 libclone_plugin.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 34256 Jan 18  2021 libpanoramix_plugin.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 13776 Jan 18  2021 libwall_plugin.so
```